# 1970s book where children pilot a dragonfly with virtual reality controls

Tags: story-identification

As a young person in the 1970s, I read a book where an inventor/professor created a (mechanical?) dragonfly that could be piloted by what we would today call virtual reality controls.  I cannot remember the plot, but a child (or children) flew the dragonfly around and once got it stuck in honey.  The hand controls gave the sensation of that stickiness.  If I remember right, the "headset" worn by the pilot also had multiple screens to show the various points of view of the dragonfly's eyes.

Comment: There was another, it was a collection of adventures of a group of kids (and I am trying to find the name myself, I still have the book somewhere), where one of the 'adventures' involved something exactly like this - they could squeeze the knobs and get feedback of the claws closing.

Answer (score 9):

I'm almost positive you're talking about "[Danny Dunn, Invisible Boy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Dunn,_Invisible_Boy)"

Comment: That's what came to my mind as well. I didn't remember the honey, but I found some links that mention it. Unfortunately, they're links that will decay soon: an [eBay listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Danny-Dunn-Invisible-Boy-pb-Science-Fiction-by-Jay-Williams-Raymond-Abrashkin-/370823824142), and a text-only [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MlOY8OqAR3YJ:twoguysbooks.blogspot.com/2010/01/when-i-was-kid-my-parents-sent-me-to.html&client=firefox-a&hs=afw&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1) (from a blog that was removed for trying to upload .bin files).

Comment: Ditto for me.  A great series for young adults.

Comment: Definitely Danny Dunn, Invisible Boy. I have a copy. Joe flew the dragonfly into a beehive.