# Book where children are empathically bonded to giant dragonflies and gain the ability to see things by their scent

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book in the 80's (not sure when it was published, sadly can't even remember what the cover looked like) about a young girl who was sent to live with distant family, was forced to drink some strange liquid, which caused her to become empathically bonded to some sort of giant dragonfly and gain the ability to see the world with scent instead of vision.

Comment: Also see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/39273/19561.

Answer (score 1):

People of the Sky by Clare Bell

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the right answer and how this book matches the description?